# Wrap between two tags jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How can i wrap "extra text" in one div  with jquery ?
The extra text can be different,and contain different html tags.

```
<i> text </i>
extra text
<p> text </p>
```

Comment: Please use the search: [`[jquery] wrap text nodes`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+wrap+text+nodes)

Comment: My question is: Why?

Comment: working on userscript for one site,so i can't change layout 
besides this way

Answer (score 0):

You can use contents, and filter by node type (3 is for text node):

But first you have to wrap whole HTML with one div:

```
<div class="demo"><i> text </i>extra text<p> text </p></div>
```

and then use below script:

```
$( ".demo" )
  .contents()
  .filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3;  
  })
  .wrap( "<div></div>" );
```

Example: **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vijayrami/wbz08gmn/11/)**

See also: [Node Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType), at MDC

Comment: please tell me more clear...is that "extra text" without having any html tag or have any html tag within it ??

Comment: extra text will be a forum's post text,so it can contain html tags inside